# How do i access the object created inside constructor?

Tags: java, scope

I want to create an array for each object i create, but i cant get access to it. since its scope is within the constructor.

```
class Constructor{

Constructor(int vsl)
{
        int[] array = new int[vsl];
    }

}
```

If i call this constructor by **Constructor c = new Constructor(4);**

how can i use array in my code?

Note: i want to specifically create the object inside the constructor and manipulate it using values i get from scanner object.

Comment: @Jens "global" isn't a term I would use in a java context

Comment: I advise you to take a look at tutorials on java objects before trying to code one.

Comment: You made `array` a local *variable* in your constructor; but it needs to be a *field* of your class. Thus: learn about such basics first. You dont learn basics by trial and and error, but by studying tutorials and books.

Comment: I would suggest you to initialize the int array[]  outside the constructor and then use it inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not, that array is scoped and visible only inside of the constructor

what you have to do is declare that array as a member class and initialize it in the constructor:

```
class Constructor {
    private int[] array;
    Constructor(int vsl) {
        array = new int[vsl];
    }

}
```